# Can't find an element on a webview page of an android native app using Appium

Tags: android, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, selendroid, nativeapplication

I am not able to find the elements from android.webkit.webview package using java appium script.

How to get the userText field and password field locators.so that i can pass the value to UI using the Appium script.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem with UIAutomator so many times. Try going to some other screen, fetch the elements of that screen and then come back to this screen again. Try to fetch the elements again and should work.

Comment: Hi this solutions is not working for me still can't locate the elements

Comment: this issue come up with the Hybrid App

Comment: Has anyone figured this out ?